Expose a new graphql endpoint from spring boot application using dgs framework
I registered the bean, when trying to hit graphql endpoint from postman the request is not reaching to DGSFetcher class to perform action
Below is the code i wrote for registering new graphql endpoint "/graphql2"
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean<AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet> GraphQLServlet() throws IOException {
    Path path = Paths.get("schema/schema.graphql");
    String sdl = new String(Files.readAllBytes(path));
    TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(sdl);
    RuntimeWiring wiring = buildRuntimeWiring(typeRegistry);
    GraphQLSchema schema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, wiring);
    GraphQLHttpServlet graphQLHttpServlet = GraphQLHttpServlet.with(schema);
    ServletRegistrationBean<AbstractGraphQLHttpServlet> registration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(
            graphQLHttpServlet, "/graphql2");
    registration.setName("Another GraphQL Endpoint");
    return registration;
}

private RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring(TypeDefinitionRegistry registry) {
    return EchoingWiringFactory.newEchoingWiring(wiring -> {
        Map<String, ScalarTypeDefinition> scalars = registry.scalars();
        scalars.forEach((name, v) -> {
            if (!ScalarInfo.isGraphqlSpecifiedScalar(name)) {
                wiring.scalar(fakeScalar(name));
            }
        });
    });
}

enter image description here
